# How to change the log level of a MR job

Tags: hadoop, logging, mapreduce

I am trying to change the log level of a MR job, I used the following command :

```
hadoop jar appMR.jar MainMR -Dmapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG <args...>
```

but the `-Dmapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG` goes as the first argument to the job.
 Is there any way to do this only for a specific MR job without changes the level in the log4j properties file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may only use the -Dname=value form if your main class implements the
Tool interface and gets invoked via the ToolRunner utility. Check the Tool
javadoc example and model your implementation around it:
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html
(Harsh J)

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/How-to-change-the-log-level-of-a-MR-job/m-p/59245#M3264?eid=3&aid=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="DEBUG,console"
```

Then run your `hadoop jar` command.

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToConfigure (Under **Environment Variables**)
[image]

Comment: This changes the log level for Hadoop ie it logs information about the communication between namenode and datanode.  I would like to change the log level of MapReduce (mapper/reducer).

Comment: What did you actually do?  The Hadoop project includes HDFS, MapReduce and YARN so the logger works for all components.  You can verify this by running an example jar and playing around with the HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER settings.